# Sitecore getting started template does not work with the training

Tags: training-certification

im doing the Sitecore Training XM/XP 10 for Developers.
https://learning.sitecore.com/learn/lp/10/xmxp-10-for-developers

In the training they show me how to use the getting started template, which I've had no trouble getting set up and running. The issue I'm having is that the current getting started templates seem to only be for the headless versions of sitecore, and they seem to not be using the headless version of sitecore in the training itself.

The code provided in the training does not match and the solutions have different projects.

Solution in the training:

[image: Sitecore Project From Training videos]

My solution created from the getting started template:

[image: Getting started template solution]

Are there any resources out there on how to setup a project that is not headless and or matches the one that they are using in this training so that i am actually able to follow along in my own code?

I am new to Sitecore and have not been able to find anything useful online.

Thanks!

Comment: So i am pretty confident that they are using a sitecore 9.3 in a sitecore TEN training i have found a rescource to install sitecore 10.3 in what i hope is a non headless form. 

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/how-to-install-sitecore-10-3-using-sitecore-install-assistant

will update with an answer when/if I find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys so the Getting started template is only for headless development, if you are going to be using headless than that is fine although the training is showing you how to do non-headless stuff and is also using a Sitecore 9.3 instance for Sitecore TEN training.

if you want to actually follow along with code and such in the XM/XP 10 for Developers you will need(I'm sure there's other ways but I'm new to Sitecore and don't know them) to install a local Sitecore instance using the Sitecore install Assistant (SIA)

you can follow this guide here:

you will need to be a system admin and have a local sql server set up.

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/how-to-install-sitecore-10-3-using-sitecore-install-assistant
Microsoft recently made the trust server ssl boolean for connection string default to false, you can remedy this by going in to the jsons in the installer and setting it to true.

once you have it installed you will need to set up a visual studio solution so you can push your code to your local sitecore instance.

I followed this guide here and did not have any issues:
https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/01/09/creating-a-visual-studio-solution/

I would like to point out that Sitecore is a multi billion dollar company by the way. I think the quality of the training and information around set up is just flat out unacceptable.

Feel free to comment on this post and I will help you out if I can.